# An unhandled exception of type 'System.OverflowException' Visual Basic WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

What is System.OverflowException?

```
    Private Sub buttonSD_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles buttonSD.Click
        AngkaPertama = textBox1.Text
        AngkaKedua = textBox2.Text

        If Kalkulasi = "+" Then
            Hasil = AngkaPertama + AngkaKedua
        ElseIf Kalkulasi = "-" Then
            Hasil = AngkaPertama - AngkaKedua
        ElseIf Kalkulasi = "*" Then
            Hasil = AngkaPertama * AngkaKedua
        ElseIf Kalkulasi = "/" Then
            Hasil = AngkaPertama / AngkaKedua
        End If

        textBoxHasil.Text = Hasil
    End Sub
```

i use Long, do i need to use ULong?

Comment: Division in probably the problem. A long divided by a long can certainly produce a double. Also check for division by zero.

Comment: As a matter of fact, the result of a long / long is always a double.

Comment: `Option Explicit`/`Option Strict` - at the moment your variables are `Variant`s and VB.Net is guessing what the should really be. In addition, you are taking `String`s and then doing arithmetic without any explicit conversion.

Comment: @AJD : `Variant` doesn't exist in VB.NET. If anything they'd be `Object`s. However I think the OP has declared the variables elsewhere and just missed showing us the declaration. `Option Explicit` is on by default and I doubt that the OP has disabled it.

Comment: @VisualVincent: Thanks - I have been swapping between the two languages lately - kinda confusing myself!

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a Try/Catch around this, this is not a safe subroutine.  The addition as well as the multiplication can easily throw an OverflowException.

Overflow can happen when you are trying to assign the result to a datatype that can't handle that large of an amount: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.overflowexception(v=vs.110).aspx

For example, something like this would throw an OverFlow:

```
Dim intType As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Long.MaxValue)
```

Might I suggest trying something safer like this:

```
Private Sub buttonSD_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles buttonSD.Click
    Try
        AngkaPertama = textBox1.Text
        AngkaKedua = textBox2.Text

        If Kalkulasi = "+" Then
            Hasil = AngkaPertama + AngkaKedua
        ElseIf Kalkulasi = "-" Then
            Hasil = AngkaPertama - AngkaKedua
        ElseIf Kalkulasi = "*" Then
            Hasil = AngkaPertama * AngkaKedua
        ElseIf Kalkulasi = "/" Then
            Hasil = AngkaPertama / AngkaKedua
        End If

        textBoxHasil.Text = Hasil
    Catch sofEx As OverflowException
        'put error in result box, or log it, or something
        textBoxHasil.Text = "Error: result too large"
    Catch ex As Exception
        'some other exception
        textBoxHasil.Text = ex.Message
    End Try
End Sub
```